# Копирование одной отсортированной коллекции в другую с сохранением условия сортировки

Tags: java, сортировка

Я пытаюсь создать промежуточный результат при формировании отсортированной очереди `PriorityBlockingQueue`.
Первая очередь заполняется коллекцией `threads` объектов `Student`

```java
PriorityBlockingQueue<Student> priorityQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(threads.size(), new StudentComparator());
priorityQueue.addAll(threads);
```

Компаратор для сортировки - это поле `prioritet` объекта `Student`

```java
class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        if (o1 == o2) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (o1 == null) {
            return -1; // o1 < o2
        }
        if (o2 == null) {
            return 1; // o1 > o2
        }
        int s = o1.getPrioritet() - o2.getPrioritet();
        if (s != 0) {
            return s;
        }
        return o1.getNameStudent().compareTo(o2.getNameStudent());
    }
}
```

В цикле программы сохраняется промежуточный результат и часть объектов (не все) сохраняется в другую `PriorityBlockingQueue`:

```java
while (true) {
    currentStudent = threadsQueueFCFS.take();
    priorityQueueTemp = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(studentsList.size(), new StudentComparator());
    priorityQueueTemp.add(currentStudent);
    // ...
    break;
}
```

и затем этот промежуточный результат должен снова вернуться в первоначальную коллекцию:

```java
for (Student student : priorityQueueTemp) {
    threadsQueueFCFS.add(student);
}
priorityQueueTemp.clear();
System.out.println(threadsQueueFCFS);
```

Результат вывода:

```
1 [Student{name='Студент1', prioritet=1, burst=2}, Student{name='Студент3', prioritet=3, burst=2}, Student{name='Студент2', prioritet=6, burst=1}]
2 [Student{name='Студент1', prioritet=1, burst=2}, Student{name='Студент3', prioritet=3, burst=2}, Student{name='Студент2', prioritet=6, burst=1}]
3 [Student{name='Студент1', prioritet=1, burst=2}, Student{name='Студент3', prioritet=3, burst=2}, Student{name='Студент2', prioritet=6, burst=1}]
4 [Student{name='Студент1', prioritet=1, burst=2}, Student{name='Студент3', prioritet=3, burst=2}, Student{name='Студент2', prioritet=6, burst=1}]
5 [Student{name='Студент1', prioritet=1, burst=2}, Student{name='Студент2', prioritet=6, burst=1}, Student{name='Студент3', prioritet=3, burst=2}]
```

Как видно, на пятом проходе нарушился порядок сортировки.
С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более удобная инициализация компаратора, эквивалентная представленному методу `StudentComparator::compare(Student s1, Student s2)`, выглядит следующим образом:

```java
Comparator<Student> comparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(
        Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getPrioritet)
                  .thenComparing(Student::getNameStudent)
);
```

Обычный компаратор `comparingInt(Student::getPrioritet)` выбросит `NullPointerException`, если входные данные будут содержать `null` значения, а также значения с равным приоритетом не будут отсортированы по имени в алфавитном порядке в отличие от первоначальной реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено в неверной работе алгоритма составления временного списка, в данном тексте этого не видно. Весь остальной алгоритм описанный мной работает правильно, только сделал более удобную инициализацию компаратора

```
Comparator<Student> comparator = comparingInt(Student::getPrioritet);
```